# Divide first derivative with initial function

Tags: calculus

Say we have function $f(x)$ and its first derivative $f'(x)$. What do we get when we take $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ ?

I see this a lot in the mathematics of economic models, but I don't quite get the intuition behind such an operation.

Thanks!

Comment: Well you could write that as $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$. As for a physical interpretation, what you're doing is you're normalizing the derivative by the function value. So if you expect your derivative to somehow strongly depend on the function value, this might be a good thing to do. It can give you a "regularized" way to look at the rate of change.

Comment: The "rate of return" of an investment that has value $f(t)$ at time $t$ is precisely your ratio.

Comment: What about elasticity of demand. ?  See that definition

Comment: @Shailesh this is technically semi-elasticity of $f$.

Comment: @charles hudgins.  Of course. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a quantity $f$ depends on $x$. Let $\%\Delta f$ denote the percent change in $f$ and $\%\Delta x$ denote the percent change in $x$ for a change $\Delta x$. Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\%\Delta f}{\%\Delta x} 
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x + h)}{f(x)} - 1}{\frac{x + h}{x} - 1}
\\&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{f(x)}}{\frac{(x + h) - x}{x}} 
\\&= \frac{x}{f(x)} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} 
= \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)}
\end{align}
In other words
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \approx \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{\% \Delta f}{\% \Delta x}
$$
for a small $\Delta x$. On the other hand, $x \cdot \%\Delta x = \Delta x$. Thus
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \Delta x \approx \%\Delta f
$$
This says that we can estimate the percent change in $f$, i.e. $\%\Delta f$, by calculating $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \Delta x$. If you don't mind the abuse of language, you might even say that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is the derivative of the percent change in $f$  with respect to $x$. Or, more informally, it's the percent change in $f$ per change in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\times100$ gives the percentage change for  $f(x)$
You can relate it to the usual percentage change calculations, which is similar to $\frac{\Delta N}{N}\times 100$

Comment: The units don't seem to check out in this claim. Percent change should be dimensionless, but $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \times 100$ will have units of $1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

And, of course, $\dfrac {f^{'}(x)}{f(x)}$ is the drivative of $\log(f(x))$.  So in applications in which log scale is an appropriate choice for the response, this expression will arise frequently.